# python Matplotlib -- Multiple Chart Objects?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I use `matplotlib` to create many different *chart objects* and then have the ability to control each **chart** object separately (without affecting the other chart objects)?

Ideally, I'd like to have something of the following:

**# creating the chart handler object**

chartHandler = ChartHandler()

**# plotting some values for chart *#0***

chartHandler[0].plot( range(0,100) )

**# plotting some values for chart *#5***

chartHandler[5].plot( range(500,700) )

Comment: are you looking for [subplot](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are talking about something that I haven't dealt with in `matplotlib` yet, I think that what you are looking for is `figure.add_subplot()`.  You should be able to capture the return from each `figure.add_subplot()` and operate on each individually from then on, kind of like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Create an 11x5 figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,5))

#Create subplots[0]
subplts = []
subplt = fig.add_subplot(121)
subplts.append(subplt)

#Create subplots[1:20]
for xind in range(4,8):
    for yind in range(0,5):
        subplt = fig.add_subplot(5,8,(yind*8+xind))
        subplts.append(subplt)

plt.show()
```

It should be noted that there are a few problems with the above script.  Mainly, the subplots overlap slightly.  This can be solved using the position keyword to `add_subplot` and some simple math.

In any case, you can now modify each subplot by referencing its index in `subplots`.  It should be pretty simple to add plots, modify ranges, etc.

Comment: that you Vorticity -- this has been very helpful!